# array of objects set to be parameter when using POST request of Alamofire

Tags: ios, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to POST a request to the server, the body of the request contains one parameter that in the form of :

```js
list: [ { "phone":"13917115283", "name": "Sky" }, { "phone":"13689652145", "name": "RJ" } ]
```

Any idea how to post such a request? Thanks

Comment: its the complete post request you want ?
It should be inside [ ] or { }..Which one you want ?

Comment: my answer doesn't solves your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this easily by using **[SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)**

Install it via Cocoapods or manually.
For manually you can simply download and add the SwiftyJSON.xcodeproj file in your workspace.

Add SwiftyJSON framework for iOS in Build Phases

[image]

Now simply import it in your ViewController

```
 import SwiftyJSON
```

Even after importing if Xcode doesn't recognize it.Clean and build it.

**Code**

```
var arrDic: NSArray = [
      ["phone": "13917115283", "name": "Sky"]
    , ["phone": "13689652145", "name": "RJ"]
                        ]
let response = [ "list" : JSON(arrDic) ]

print(JSON(response))
```

**Final Output**

[image]