# Create complex [String:AnyObject] for Alamofire parameters

Tags: ios, rest, swift2, alamofire

it's my first project with Swift, so be patient.
I'm trying to integrate my REST services using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). I have some troubles with building of the parameters field in case of complex JSON structure.

The server needs a structure like this:

```
{
  "event": {
    "name": "string",
    "duration": 1,
    "lat": 45.0,
    "lon": 45.0,
    "deadline": "2015-12-01T10:07:14.017Z"
  },
  "proposals": [
    "2015-11-01T10:07:14.017Z"
  ],
  "invitations": [
    {
      "user": 0,
      "phone": "string",
      "email": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

where proposals is an array of NSDate and invitations is an array of Dictionary, both with variable length.

At the moment, I'm trying to create a `NSMutableDictionary`, populate it with the necessary fields and the end convert it to a `[String: AnyObject]`

It is an example for the event and proposal fields:

```
var parameters: [String:AnyObject] = [
"event" : "",
"proposals": "",
"invitations": "",
]

if let event = mutableParameters.objectForKey("event") as? [String:AnyObject] {
parameters.updateValue(event, forKey: "event")
}

if let prop = mutableParameters.objectForKey("proposals") as? [String:AnyObject] {
parameters.updateValue(prop, forKey: "proposals")
}
```

But the second if doesn't entry in the true branch.

Any suggestions? If someone have a better solution, this will be well-accepted!

Comment: this might helps you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061565/array-of-objects-set-to-be-parameter-when-using-post-request-of-alamofire/33102335#33102335

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you're casting `mutableParameters.objectForKey("proposals")` as a `[String:AnyObject]` dictionary, but this should be `[String]`, an array of Strings:

```
if let prop = mutableParameters.objectForKey("proposals") as? [String] {
    parameters.updateValue(prop, forKey: "proposals")
}
```

**UPDATE**

It's better to just make a Swift dictionary and use  `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
let source: [String:AnyObject] = ["event" : ["name": "welcome", "duration": "1", "lat": 45.0,"lon": 45.0,"deadline": "2015-12-01T10:07:14.017Z"], "proposals": ["2015-12-01T10:07:14.017Z"], "invitations": [["user": "eric", "phone": "555", "email": "none"]]]

do {
    let dictionaryAsJSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(source, options: [])
    // send it to your server, or...
    if let jsonDataAsString = NSString(data: dictionaryAsJSONData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        // send this
        print(jsonDataAsString)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Here `jsonDataAsString` is:

> {"proposals":["2015-12-01T10:07:14.017Z"],"invitations":[{"email":"none","user":"eric","phone":"555"}],"event":{"lon":45,"deadline":"2015-12-01T10:07:14.017Z","duration":"1","lat":45,"name":"welcome"}}

Comment: Hi @Eric D., I'm sorry but your solution doesn't work, the code doesn't enter in the true branch.

Comment: Then it means that your `mutableParameters.objectForKey("proposals")` is not an array of strings (but in your question, *it is*). I've updated my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Ah, you are right! I forgot to convert the nsdate to string! :-O

Comment: But this approach is very complex, do you have any suggestion for the NSMutableDictionary to [String:AnyObject] convertion?

Comment: I thought maybe you had a reason to do it like that so I didn't mention it, but it could be improved indeed. I'd say just create a Swift dictionary then use `NSSerialization` to make it JSON data. If you need a JSON *string*, then reserialize this data as a string. Or of course you could use an external library like SwiftyJSON but I find it seriously overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: @Zeb Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Typical JSON handling is messy](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#why-is-the-typical-json-handling-in-swift-not-good)

You can easily achieve this easily by using [**SwiftyJSON**](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Install it via Cocoapods or manually. For manually you can simply download and add the SwiftyJSON.xcodeproj file in your workspace.

Add SwiftyJSON framework for iOS in Build Phases

[image]

Now simply import it in your ViewController

```
import SwiftyJSON
```

Even after importing if Xcode doesn't recognize it.Clean and build it.

> **Code**

```
 let dic1 = ["name": "string", "duration": "1", "lat": 45.0,"lon": 45.0,"deadline": "2015-12-01T10:07:14.017Z"]
 let dic2 = ["2015-12-01T10:07:14.017Z"]
 let dic3 = [["user": "string", "phone": "1", "email": "asd"]]

 let response = [ "event" : dic1,"proposals": dic2,"invitations": dic3]
 print(JSON(response))
```

> **Output**

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but this solution doesn't work. It is the error: `Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)`

Comment: you have to convert NSDate to String or NSString and then use it